# when would failbit be set while executing a getline function call in c++

Tags: c++, file, getline

when would getline in c++ fail?

I have a big snippet of code which I am unable to paste in its entirety for multifarious reasons. I am trying to read from a file , which I know exists and contains data, using getline in C++. But getline fails returning error 123-invalid name(output of getlasterror). I looked up the error code which baffles me even more.

I do error check while opening the file. So I am positive that I have the handle to the file.
Please bear with me for not pasting the code. I am new to c++ and especially in windows. Any suggestions or insights about getline would help. I am trying to read a file which is dumped by a compiler.

This is an extract from the code

```
ifstream inFile("C:\...\ash.txt",ios::in);

string singleLine;

getline(inFile,singleLine);
```

singleLine is empty ! I am doing something silly..pls point that out to me! appreciate it

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

I checked for the ios members and found that fail bit is set. Why would the fail bit be set? the file does exist and also I was wondering if how windows exposes file extensions could cause a problem . That doesnt seem to the problem. What am i missing?

Comment: paste then just the opening of the file and the reading with getline...

Comment: it might have reached EOF. check the stream if it is `bad()`

Comment: @hexa i checked for the bad bit..Fail bit is the one thats failing

Comment: Because you are not specifying the correct path to the file. The '\' character is an escape. Also the ... seems a bit fishy are you just trying to be brief in you past (don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `fail` bit is set, it is probably because you didn't successfully open the file.  Check whether `ifFile.is_open()` returns true; if not, then then probably indicates that the file is not open correctly.  You might not have permissions, or you may need to escape the string properly, or the file may be locked.

You should also check if `fail` is set both before and after the call to `getline`.  If it's before, that probably means that the file isn't open.  If it's after, it could mean that the file is empty.

It may be the case that Windows is hiding the true file extension from you.  The file name might actually be named `ash.txt.txt`, for example, if you have Explorer configured to hide file extensions.  That might be worth investigating if the file isn't open.

Answer (score 4):

`GetLastError` only tells you about Win32 API calls, which `std::getline` is not.

Check the members of the iostream that failed, e.g. `rdstate()`.

Calling `ios::exceptions(eofbit | failbit | badbit)` before `getline` and catching the resulting exception might or might not get you a more descriptive error message.

Comment: it seems like the failbit is set

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to escape the backslashes in the file path?

Answer (score 0):

It failed to open the file.

This is becuase you did not specify the correct path.

This is because you used the ancient windows convention of \ as a path separator.
Which also happens to be the escape character in C.

Which is why Windows  lets you use / as a path separator (and has done for over a decade) because the use of '/' is so error prone.

Your path should be:

```
ifstream inFile("C:\\...\\ash.txt");

// Or my preference

ifstream inFile("C:/.../ash.txt");
```

Or even better use boost.

Answer (score -1):

Getline IIRC is meant for c_strings and the string is the first argument, not the second.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

You're attempting to use a normal string, which (I could be wrong) doesn't work with getline.

Comment: There is another version of the getline which takes in string.